# taxonomy name filter to get terms with special characters

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am getting my term description using `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()`.

I'm having problems with term names like "barnes & noble" and "Café"; I guess it must have something to do with the special characters. How can I filter my taxonomy name input the best way to get back term results?

I'm using the function in a views-view-list.tpl.php template, where `$title` is outputting the taxonomy; then I use `$title` with the following code.

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($title, 'places');
```

`$title` seems to be stripped from all kind of htmltags - its plain text.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting ? I just tested the same in d7 instance and i don't see any with above terms ?

Comment: Hi Anil,
I'm not getting any errors, just an empty array as no taxonomy by that name exist.

Comment: I just created two terms under tags vocab and called $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name("barnes & noble");
drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($term, 1) . "</pre>");  It worked perfectly !!

Comment: Hi Anil,
You are right.
I guess the problem must be elsewhere then.

Comment: How are you printing details ? Can you post your code ?

Comment: I have updated above.

Comment: May you provide more code from that template file? A single line of code is not sufficient to answer the question. It could be there is a typo, or a mistake in the code, and nobody will tell you there is, without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, it might seam simple, but its sure its in this line. $terms should be an array after using the function, and on $title's containing & the array returns empty. All other taxonomy returns an array containing the taxonomy details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only the & charter there was making problems.
This was the solution:

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $title), 'places');
```